# Redirect ActionResult from httpPost ActionResult view not show

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm post my anguler model to mvc HttpPost ActionResult. after i want to Redirect  Action Contact view. code is running but Contact view not displaying.

**First ActionResult Call**

```
$scope.saveSubs = function () {
   var sub = {Des: $scope.des.slice($scope.des.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, 
                   $scope.des.lastIndexOf(")")),
};

$http.post('/Home/HotelSearch', sub);
```

This is working. but after this call i want to redirect to another ActionResult.

**HttpPost ActionResult**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult HotelSearch(HotelBooking hotelBooking)
{  
   ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
   TempData["LoginData"] = hotelBooking;
   return RedirectToAction("Contact");
}
```

**Second ActionResult**

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
   ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
   return View("Contact");
}
```

This View not viewing. can i know what is this problem?

Comment: I do not think that you can redirect _the whole browser page_ from within an Ajax call. Usually I do either return a Partial View and add it to the DOM upon the Ajax call return; or I return a string with an URL to redirect client-side through `location.href` upon the Ajax call return.

Comment: ajax call working.second RedirectToAction is not viewing. debug point is reaching . but view not working.

Comment: return jsonresult to your ajax call and  in success callback you can redirect page you want

Comment: replace RedirectToAction("Contact"); with View("Contact",model) where model is the populated model needed by contract view.

Answer (score 1):

I agreed with above comments, you can not completely redirect using ajax calls.ajax is always use for partial data/view loading. 
we can get redirect from ajax call using Json return type.

```
return Json(new {result = "Redirect", url = Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")});
```

this may help you.